# ApacheDS - UID Attribute not valid in new installed instance

Tags: ldap, apacheds

we are moving servers and i tried to import the old ApacheDS data to the new server instance, half of the data didn't worked cause the UID seems not to be allowed.

I888\G775638 is valid but if i try to change the UID to I0198\A77FD0A the value can't be changed.

Where can i configure the syntax allowed for UID Attribute?

Thanks!

I tried to take a look at the UID attribute in the ApacheDS attribute editor but didn't found a setting for the valid syntax, compared also the Code behind the attribute in both instances and there are exact the same.